# COPY INTO: How to add a partitioning?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

The command `COPY INTO` from Databricks provides an idempotent file ingestion into a delta table, see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html). From the docs, an example command looks like this:

```sql
COPY INTO delta.`target_path`
  FROM (SELECT key, index, textData, 'constant_value' FROM 'source_path')
  FILEFORMAT = CSV
  PATTERN = 'folder1/file_[a-g].csv'
  FORMAT_OPTIONS('header' = 'true')
```

However, I want my data to be ingested via a partition, which can be accomplished with the `PARTITIONED BY` command in a normal ingestion. Is it possible to execute a `COPY INTO` command with partitioning? Simply adding the partitioning clause yields the following error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'PARTITIONED' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 8, pos 0)
```

Comment: That has to be a very Databricks command since even Spark SQL 3.1.2 does not recognize it and throws a ParseException.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly from `COPY INTO`. You need to use [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html), to create table partitioned by whatever column you need, and then do the `COPY INTO` that created table - it will be then correctly partitioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is still unclear how to do so. Lets say my CREATE TABLE command looks like this: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table (idx INT, val INT, cat STRING) PARTITIONED BY (cat)`. How could I choose `example_table` as my input for COPY INTO? Where to put the csv folder path?